# Couldn't sort and filter data using angular material

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-material, angularfire, angular-material-table

I am currently using firebase as my back end for retrieving data.. and all works fine including pagination except for sorting and filtering data.. as it is getting implemented on the basis of key and not the value, and i am not sure how to fix it. here's my code..

admin-products.ts

```
import { ProductService } from './../../product.service';
import { Component, OnDestroy, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { Product } from 'src/app/models/product';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import {  MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-products',
  templateUrl: './admin-products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-products.component.css']
})
export class AdminProductsComponent implements OnDestroy, AfterViewInit{
  products: Product[] = [];
  subscription: Subscription;


  displayedColumns: string[] = ['title', 'price', 'edit'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(this.products);
  
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort | any;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator | any;

  constructor(private productService: ProductService) { 
    this.subscription = this.productService.getAll()
    .subscribe(products => {
      this.dataSource.data = products;
      console.log(this.dataSource.data);
    });
  }
  
  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }

  applyFilter(event: Event) {
    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

admin-products.html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <h2>Product Management</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <a routerLink="/admin/products/new" class="btn btn-primary float-right">New Product</a>
      </div>
    </div><br>
  
    <div class="table-container mat-elevation-z3">
      <div class="table-header">
        <mat-form-field appearance="fill"  class="example-full-width">
          <input #input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event)" placeholder="Search...">
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
  
      <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort >
    
        <!-- Title Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="title">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Title </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let product">{{ product.val.title }}</td>
        </ng-container>
    
        <!-- Price Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="price">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Price </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let product"> {{ product.val.price | currency:'USD' }} </td>
        </ng-container>
    
        <!-- Edit Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="edit" >
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let product"><a [routerLink]="['/admin/products/', product.key]">Edit</a></td>
        </ng-container>
    
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
        </tr>
      </table>
    
      <mat-paginator 
        [pageSize]="10"
        [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 25, 50, 100]">
      </mat-paginator>
    </div>
  
  </div>
```

and this is getall() method in product-service.ts

```
 getAll(): Observable<Product[] | any>{
    return this.db.list<Product>('/products').snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(
      map((actions: any[]) => {
          return actions.map((action) => ({
            key: action.key,
            val: action.payload.val() as Product,
          }));
      }));
  }
```

[for example in the image, if i do filtering it is filtered on the basis of id provided by the firebase and not the title which was expected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3Pak.jpg)

Comment: Where is your filtering/sorting not working? On the mat table?

Comment: it is working on the keys instead of values.. please check the attached image

Comment: In your **subscribe function** you need write this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(products);, else you only has an "object" with property data, but not a [MatTableDataSource](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api#MatTableDataSource) -with all the properties and methods-. You use new MatTableDataSource when defined the variable, but this only makes at first an empty MatTableDataSource.

Comment: @Eliseo i did that also but it dosen't seem to help.. the sorting and filter is still working on the basis of random keys that is generated by firebase not on the values inside of it..

Answer (score 0):

i just changed my getAll method in product.service.ts to this and it worked

```
  getAll(): Observable<Product[] | any>{
    return this.db.list<Product>('/products').snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(
      map(changes => 
        changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }))
      )
    );
  }
```

as in previous code there were two different entries each of them containing key and value so the filter and sorting method automatically took key and applied on that but in this way the c contain both (key and value) in a single entry.. hence it worked.